# Why is monero mined coins called tail emissions? Why not just call it "mined coins"?

Tags: tail-emission, mining-technical-details

Coming from bitcoin, its confusing to use new terminology sometimes. Why is it called tail-emissions vs just calling it coins mined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tail emission specifically refers to newly mined coins after Monero is mostly mined out. With Monero, the block reward slowly decreases with each block. When it eventually gets to 0.6 XMR per two minute block, it stops decreasing and flattens out at that rate. This is referred to as the tail emission, and is a characteristic of Monero that Bitcoin does not have.